# jira greenhopper rapid board release

Tags: jira, greenhopper

I am playing around with the eval of greenhopper and I set up a kanban rapid board that has a main bucket and several swim lanes.  The release button from the Done column adds any Jira in the Done column to a release.

Is there a way to just release a swim lane with that button?  So even though we have completed Jira in my main work bucket I might only want to release an urgent patch by itself.  It would be great if the release button had a few more controls over it so I could quickly just release a certain lane.

or does it??

Answer (score 1):

From what I've seen I don't think that capability exists, to release just one individual swimlane.  A hack may be to create an ad-hoc board and restrict it to the tickets that you want to release.  Obviously not a best practice, but as Greenhopper's Rapid Board func is still kind of, well, green, we've been finding that some hacks may be the only way to get the less mainstream stuff done at this time.